# Ancova: Equation for three terms, two-way interactions significant

Tags: r, anova, ancova

I have a question regarding ANCOVA. I'm trying to set up the model equation from results in R. Suppose my model formula looks like that:

y ~ A * B * x

A and B are categorical variables and x is a continuous variable.
As example, my results are the following:

A: significant (*)
B: not significant (n.s.)
x: *
A * x: *
B * x: n.s.
A * B: *
A * B * x: n.s.

I interpreted that as follows:
- the slope for each level of A is different to 0 (A * x is significant)
- the slope for each level of B is not different to 0 (B * x is not significant)
- the slope for each level of A and B is not different from each other (since A * B * x is not significant)
- the mean over all values of x is different for the at least two levels of A (since A is significant), meaning that the intercept must be different (since the slope is not different)
- the mean over all values of x is not different for the levels of B (since B is not significant)

Are these interpretations of the results correct?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why don't you fit the linear model and estimate those slopes along with their 95% confidence intervals instead of conducting all these tests? We don't care about the statistical significance of blocking factors, since they're a reflection of the design rather than the population. Are you conflating "t"/"x" or is there a time component you haven't described? Further the *results* are not the *assumptions*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the confusion with x and t... I changed it above. Now I used lsmeans to calculate confidence intervals for the means and interceps. I also used the package to do post-hoc tests on both parameters. But a new problem arises: suppose A has three levels, A1, A2 and A3. The slope is different between A1 and A2, and A1 and A3 but not between A2 and A3. Should I therefore use the same slope for A2 and A3 and another one for A1?

Comment: For dummy coded effects, the coefficient is the mean difference between units having the condition from those who do not, holding all other features fixed.